# How to add Jodit editor to dynamically added text areas?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, append, jodit

I have this JavaScript:

```
j = 0;

function add_more_additional_field() {
    $('#additional_options').append(
        '<div class="form-group row mar-btm"><div class="col-md-3"><input type="hidden" name="af_no[]" value="' +  j + '"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="af_title[]" value="" placeholder="Additional Title"></div><div class="col-md-7"><textarea class="form-control editor" name="af_options[]"></textarea></div><div class="col-md-1"><button onclick="delete_row(this)"  class="btn btn-danger btn-icon"><i class="demo-psi-recycling icon-lg"></i>Remove</button></div></div><hr/>'
    );
    j++;
    var editor = new Jodit('#additional_options .editor');
}

function delete_row(em) {
    $(em).closest('.row').remove();
    update_sku();
}
```

The function of the script is to append more form fields when clicked. This code works fine. Now I want to append a Jodit editor at each click as well. I tried doing it by attributing a unique id or class (see how I use `j` in the code above). But this code only appends the Jodit editor at the *first* text area, but doesn't add it for the other text areas..

How to append the editor to each of the text area fields?

Comment: you can set `j` as a **global** --  `window.j = 0;` And set it every time like `window.j++;`

Comment: Explain more please @Zak

Comment: @Zak, in the OP's code it is *already* a global.

Comment: j++ works differently. I use it in one of the inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line will always target the *first* element with the `editor` class:

```
new Jodit('#additional_options .editor');
```

...while you want to target the new, *last* element with that class. So use the possibility to pass a DOM element to the `Jodit` constructor. You can then get the node list of all matches, and take the *last* one of those, and pass it to the constructor:

```
new Jodit([...document.querySelectorAll('#additional_options .editor')].pop());
```